# Trouble display Chart in PDF exported from ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, pdf, layouts, chart

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and we have MS Office 2013.  I am not sure if this has a lot to do with the MS Office 2013 that ArcGIS 10.1 doesn't read...So I am sharing this with you all...

When I set it up a chart in MS office 2013. and then copy and paste to ArcGIS 10.1 it will show the chart there but when you export to any fomrat  the chart will not display.

Has anyone had any issue with it ?  Is there a way around to fix this problem. The only way is I have to do is save it in Power Point and then save it as a TIFF file and then inset it in ArcGIS .  It is okay...

The first one you see is in ArcGIS Layout View. The second one you see is export in PDF .[image: First Layout View in ArcGIS]

[image: PDF Exported]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is a common problem but I definitely run into this all the time with Office 2013. In my case when I copy and paste excel spreadsheets into layout colours disappear on export but text generally remains intact.  Copying and pasting simple spreadsheets works fine but when the spreadsheet is a little more more graphically intense or contains a graphic element such as chart then issues appear on export. The item shows fine in ArcMap layout but does not export correctly whether the map is exported to tiff, jpeg or pdf.

The crude workaround I use is what you have already suggested; convert the graphic to jpeg or tiff then add it to layout as a common image.  I usually print to PDF then open in Adobe Illustrator, crop & modify if needed and export to JPEG. Technically, ArcMap should be able to handle EMF which is a vector graphic I can also export to from Illustrator, however although it also displays correctly in the ArcMap layout, there seems to be a myriad of other font related issus when exporting. (i would have to convert all text to curves in Illustrator for this to work, an extra step and unless i need transparency it's not worth the effort) The simplest and crudest workaround for this (simple image) is thus the best.